# many plural words in a sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, parenthetical-plural

Consider these sentences:

> I created an implementation of a semaphore in terms of a mutex.

This is very easy to interpret. The author created a thing called semaphore in terms of one other thing, a mutex.

> I created an implementation of a semaphore in terms of mutexes.

This is fairly easy. The author created a thing called semaphore in terms of many mutexes.

> I created implementations of semaphores in terms of a mutex.

Asuming you need a thing mutex to create a semaphore, I think this sentence means create many semaphores in terms of a mutex. This sentence is wrong. Am I correct?

> I created implementations of semaphores in terms of mutexes.

I do not understand what this means. I don't know if it means a mutex per semaphore or many mutex per semaphore.

The real paragraph can be found here:
https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-23.html#%_sec_3.4.2

My questions are:

- Can anyone explain what the last sentence exactly mean?
- Are all my interpretations in the previous sentences correct?

Comment: You say "The real paragraph can be found here" at the linked page but I can't see any paragraph even vaguely looking like any of your examples. In fact, the language of that page is clear and well expressed, whereas your examples are difficult. Good writers would avoid the ambiguity by constructing the sentence so that the meaning is unambiguous.

Comment: @Chappo the paragraph is in exercise 3.47. I tried to make it as general as possible. Looks like I failed. But the real sentence is "give implementations of semaphores in terms of mutexes." I don't understand this sentence at all. I provided the previous sentences to show what I understand.

Comment: Ah, but you haven't quoted that sentence accurately at all. I'll write up a proper answer...

Comment: You ask: Can anyone explain what the last sentence exactly mean? But you created that sentence yourself.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is, or why it belongs here rather than somewhere like English Language Learners?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Even though it's not a great question, it meets ELU's requirements. I think the problem has been adequately explained, and from the OP's comments it's clear they're not a beginner in English.

Comment: Actually, Chappo, it’s clear that beginner or what, the OP isn’t fluent in English. Doesn’t that make it doubly likely the Question would be better addressed somewhere such as ELL?

For example, each and every use of "many" there was questionable, and importantly so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [linked source](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-23.html#%_sec_3.4.2) to the problematic sentence, under exercise 3.47, provides important background material that acts as an initial pointer to the meaning. It says:

> **Exercise 3.47.**  A semaphore (of size *n*) is a generalization of a mutex. Like a mutex, a semaphore supports acquire and release
>   operations, but it is more general in that up to *n* processes can
>   acquire it concurrently. Additional processes that attempt to acquire
>   the semaphore must wait for release operations.

Now this is a field I'm unfamiliar with, but the language here is concise and well-expressed, so even though I don't understand the technical aspects, I *can* understand that there's a relationship between semaphores and mutexes.

Then comes the sentence you've cited - only, you didn't cite it exactly, nor did you cite all of it. It says:

> Give implementations of semaphores
>
> > a. in terms of mutexes
> >     b. in terms of atomic test-and-set! operations.

The way this is worded, it's clear that the task is to ***provide some examples of how semaphores have been implemented, and distinguish between these examples based on specific parameters*** - i.e. mutexes, versus atomic test-and-set! operations.

Your original question, therefore, presents somewhat of an artificial problem in that you've constructed your own sentence in a difficult and ambiguous way, and then you've asked us to decode that ambiguity. The primary *difficulty* is that you've substituted "created" for "give", which requires a significantly different semantic response.

Even if we ignore this, the primary *solution* is to avoid the ambiguity in the first place. The wording of 3.47 does this by giving the reader an opportunity to deconstruct the meaning, via the (a) and (b) options. It separates the phrases, and in effect provides additional logical order. If there was only option (a), the writer could still have helped the reader by breaking the instruction into two parts:

> Give implementations of semaphores. Explain the implementations in
>   terms of mutexes.

To return to the four sentences you created and your interpretation of each:

**1. "implementation of a semaphore in terms of a mutex"** - yes, you're correct. Pretty simple.

**2. "implementation of a semaphore in terms of mutexes"** - *no, not necessarily.* The reference to mutexes might be *generic*, in which case it could be understood that each semaphore relates to an individual mutex. However, the construction is clumsy, and would best be avoided.

**3. "implementations of semaphores in terms of a mutex"** - yes, this sentence is wrong in the sense that it is poorly expressed. It doesn't make sense, unless it's intending to say that you started with a *single* mutex and implemented a variety of semaphores based on that one mutex - which is exactly the explanation Peter Shot gives [in his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/464538/167396). You notice that to ensure the meaning is understood, I've qualified mutex with the quantifiers "single" and "one". Since your sentence lacks the qualification, it leaves the meaning open, and therefore the sentence is confusing.

**4. "implementations of semaphores in terms of mutexes"**. Here there are multiple semaphores, but it's not possible from the wording to deduce whether each semaphore relates to a single mutex or multiple mutexes - the same issue as sentence #2. The ambiguity could be eliminated by adding a qualifier: e.g. "individual mutexes", "several mutexes", etc. As I've noted, (1) you've presented a different construction compared to the real sentence in exercise 3.47, and (2) the *reader* can't make a definite interpretation without a qualifier (but, as you're the one writing this sentence, *you* should understand what you have in mind).

Comment: I reworded the sentence so the technical things does not get in the way. Had I included the whole text of the exercise my question might be closed as off topic. Appologies for the misunderstanding. Can you explain the real meaning of "in terms of mutexes" in 3.47? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. This is the answer. The OP misunderstood the text completely and in doing so failed to see that the author was asking the reader to perform a task.

Comment: @morbidCode Always, *always* quote sources accurately, do not attempt to paraphrase unless you are supremely confident, and you weren't. Furthermore, your asking Chappo to explain the meaning of "in terms of mutexes" is ill-advised.  Chappo admitted to not being an expert in this field, so I imagine you should already be familiar with the term yourself. You can ask a new question if its meaning is so onerous that you cannot work it out.

Comment: @morbidCode In your comment you ask *can you explain the real meaning of "in terms of mutexes" in 3.47?* See what I wrote in bold italic below the quoted question in my answer. If you don't know how to respond to the question because you don't know what mutexes are or how they relate to semaphores, you'll need to ask your teacher, as that is a specialist question rather than a question of English language/usage.

Comment: This isn't obvious to someone who's not familiar with what semaphores and/or mutexes are, but 'mutex' comes from "mutually exclusive" and its whole purpose is to disallow a program from acquiring a particular mutex if another program already has it. Regarding sentence 2: One method of implementing a semaphore is to use multiple mutexes. Regarding sentences 3&4: A single semaphore implemented via mutexes can't be made using a single mutex, so if you are aware of the definition quoted at the start of your answer, it becomes obvious that 3 is wrong, and 4 requires multiple mutexes per semaphore.

Comment: @3D1T0R excellent! Your explanation is the missing ingredient. However, isn't it possible that in sentence 4, each semaphore could have a single mutex, provided that no two semaphores shared the same mutex? If this is possible, then the sentence correctly expresses that there are multiple semaphores and multiple mutexes, but leaves open the number of mutexes *per semaphore*.

Comment: As an English sentence, yes, it's open for interpretation, however knowing that mutex means mutually exclusive, a semaphore implemented by using a single mutex is nothing more than that mutex already was, as only one program can acquire that one mutex at a time. Think of it this way: Program A starts 9 instances of program B. If a single mutex is used, one instance will run, and all others will fail to get the mutex, and either exit, or wait their turn. If instead a semaphore implemented using 4 mutexes is used, it launches B1-B4, then B5-B9 all either fail or wait for the others to release…

Comment: … their mutex. Assuming B5-B9 wait, then when one of the running processes is done it releases its mutex, then one of the waiting ones takes it and runs, until all 9 instances have finished. If you were to implement this semaphore with only a single mutex, only one would be able to run at a time, because there would only be one mutex available for them, and that 'semaphore' would really just be a mutex.

Answer (score 2):

To answer one of your questions, if there is one mutex and many semaphores, the third sentence is completely correct.

Consider

> variations on a theme,

which is a common phrase in titles of classical music pieces.

*Theme* is singular, and *variations* is plural, because there are many variations and one theme.

Or you could say

> I based many of my stories on members of that family.

Here, there's only one family, but it has lots of members, and there are many stories based on one or more of these members.

Comment: The OP asked if this third sentence was wrong, and in my answer I initially said yes, but I've since edited my answer to qualify that the way it's *expressed* is wrong, but your analysis is correct.

Comment: @Chappo: I agree. It's in some sense wrong in that specific context, but only because in this context, it's hard to imagine implementing many semaphores based on a single mutex.